Why different results for linear regression in sem() from lavaan and lm()?
thanks for reading this.
I am a student trying to understand more about statistics for social science questions. I am trying to build equivalence in R between the sem() function in {lavvan} and the lm() function in {stats} for a simple linear regression with one outcome and one predictor, both of which are not latent variables. However, even though I could obtain the same parameter estimate for the model, the estimated standard errors are slightly different, no matter which estimator I use. An example is attached below:
#load libraries
library(lavaan)

#Create a data frame
set.seed(1231)
n <- 100 #number of observations

X <- rnorm(n, mean = 50, sd = 10)
Y <- rnorm(n, mean = 65, sd = 8)

df <- data.frame(X, Y)

#using the lm() function
lm <- lm(Y ~ X, data = df)
summary(lm)

#using the sem() function from lavaan
model_sem <- 'Y~X'
sem <- sem(model_sem, estimator = "ML", se = "standard", data = df)
summary(sem, nd = 7)

Results from the current example:

From the lm() output

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 67.30819    4.37739   15.38   <2e-16
X           -0.04116    0.08571   -0.48    0.632    


From the sem() output

Regressions:
                       Estimate      Std.Err      z-value      P(>|z|)
  Y ~                                                                 
    X                -0.0411622    0.0848524   -0.4851035    0.6276029

The parameter estimate is equal while the SEs for the parameter and the p values are slight different. I also inspected the variance-covariance matrix from both models using vcov() function in {stats4}.
vcov(lm)[c("X"),c("X")]
[1] 0.00734687
vcov(sem)[c("Y~X"),c("Y~X")]
[1] 0.007199932

I tried to hand calculate the variance-covariance matrix from the lm() output and successfully did it. However, I cannot find functions to extract the observed (or expected) information matrix from sem() or calculate the log-likelihood function that was used according to the lavaan documentation. Is it possible to achieve equivalence between the two in this specific case? Why (where did I do wrong) or why not (what is the difference, is it the model estimation and specification or just due to the packages)?
Thank you so much!

0.007199932 / 0.00734687 = 98/100, check the degrees of freedom in the sem model.

Thank you @Roland for noticing this! The df in the sem output is 0. Correct me if I am wrong, I am estimating three parameters (the β coefficient and variance of X and Y) with three pieces of information (variance of X and Y and covariance between X and Y). I think I am getting something with your response since 0.007199932 / 0.00734687 = 98/100 and the numerator is the df in the lm model while the denominator is the sample size. I am still confused why knowing the df in the sem model is helpful and why are they different. Thank you so much!

In brief, the difference is that the lavaan package function is using maximum likelihood for the estimation protocol.  Whereas the lm function is using ordinary least squares.  Both produce the same estimate in this case, but the estimated standard error will be slightly different (but relatively close for the given sample size).

And this will get closer as the sample size increases.

Thank you so much for the response! I get that the parameter estimation is equivalent for MLE and OLS in this case-that's why I used it. I am aware that the OLS estimation of SE involves the sample size as the denominator. How is this different from the estimation of the Hessian matrix in relation to sample size? Could you tell me more about this with calculation/formula or direct me to other resources? Thank you!

To add to @Gregg H's answer, if you specify that the likelihood is to be Wishart, rather than normal, the standard errors are closer (0.0852799 for ML-Wishart, 0.0848524 for ML normal, and 0.08571 for OLS). Additionally, with a larger sample, the discrepancy is also smaller.
There's more here:
https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/est.html#ml-estimation-wishart-versus-normal
